# dragging images around the screen using swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6

I have tried this method

```
@IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

 let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
 if let view = recognizer.view {
  view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                        y:view.center.y + translation.y)
}
 recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
}
```

It is working but the problem is that when I use this method on multiple images it create some issues for example,
when drag one image and change its position but when I click and drag second image . My first image come back to original position.
Here are the images I am getting from a scroll view: 
When I click second image 1st image also go the original position

[image]

I am dragging an image its fine here

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Auto Layout is running a putting your images back to where the constraints say they should be.

The easiest way to get around this is to create your images in code instead of creating them in the Storyboard.

Something like:

```
let lightBulb = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 100, 50, 50))
lightBulb.image = UIImage(named: "lightBulb")
lightBulb.contentMode = .ScaleToFill
lightBulb.userInteractionEnabled = true

lightBulb.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePan:"))

self.view.addSubview(lightBulb)
```

Comment: i tried this but nothing is showing up on screen i have written this code on the back of a button action

Comment: I just tried this and it does work.  Perhaps you should create an `@IBOutlet` to the content view of the scroll view to make it easier to add items.   `@IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!` and hook that to the content view of your scroll view.  Then add the lightBulb like this: `contentView.addSubview(lightBulb)`.

Comment: i am getting this "UIScrollView does not have a member named contentView"      and i want to pick the images from scroll view and then display it to the main view

Comment: The `addSubview` call should be on whichever view you want to display the images.  I misunderstood and thought you want to display them on the scrollView.  `self.view.addSubview(lightBulb)` instead.

Comment: i did this :   self.view.addsubview(lightbulb)    now image is showing on view but when i drag it, it move too fast and disappear from the screen

Comment: Check your `panHandler` routine.  It sounds like you are missing the `recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)` part.

Comment: @vacawama Thanks, I have used your code now i want to set boundaries for that image i mean i have image inside one view so now i want to make it drag able within that view only, How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 9):

```
class DraggableImageView: UIImageView {


var dragStartPositionRelativeToCenter : CGPoint?

override init(image: UIImage!) {
    super.init(image: image)

    self.userInteractionEnabled = true   //< w00000t!!!1

    addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePan:"))

    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    layer.shadowRadius = 2
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func handlePan(nizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer!) {
    if nizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
        let locationInView = nizer.locationInView(superview)
        dragStartPositionRelativeToCenter = CGPoint(x: locationInView.x - center.x, y: locationInView.y - center.y)

        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 20)
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        layer.shadowRadius = 6

        return
    }

    if nizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
        dragStartPositionRelativeToCenter = nil

        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        layer.shadowRadius = 2

        return
    }

    let locationInView = nizer.locationInView(superview)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1) {
        self.center = CGPoint(x: locationInView.x - self.dragStartPositionRelativeToCenter!.x,
            y: locationInView.y - self.dragStartPositionRelativeToCenter!.y)
    }
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
// Drawing code
}
*/   
}
```

Comment: How can i use this class?

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 4 and above

In viewDidLoad() set the gesture and the add the following method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.panGesture))
    yourView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
}

@objc func panGesture(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    var relativePosition: CGPoint?
    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began {
        let locationInView = sender.location(in: super.view)
        relativePosition = CGPoint(x: locationInView.x - (sender.view?.center.x ?? 0.0), y: locationInView.y - (sender.view?.center.y ?? 0.0))
        return
    }
    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended {
        relativePosition = nil
        return
    }
    let locationInView = sender.location(in: super.view)
    guard let pos = relativePosition else {
        return
    }
    sender.view?.center = CGPoint(x: locationInView.x - pos.x,
                                  y: locationInView.y - pos.y)
}
```